# pset1 meal time but check fails

Tags: python, cs50

The problem require to convert user's input to time and print meal time (i.e lunch time, dinner time e.t.c)
[image]

When I test my code with the time provided in the problem I get the expected output.

[image]Sadly, when I run check it fails.

Here is my code

```
def main():
    # ask user for input
    time_input = input("Time: ").strip().split(":")
    # convert time to decimal
    time = convert(time_input)

    # check time and print meal time
    if time >= 7.0 and time <= 8.0:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif time >= 12.0 and time <= 13.0:
        print("lunch time")

    elif time >= 18.0 and time <= 19.0:
        print("dinner time")



def convert(t):
    # convert string to float(hour)
    hour = float(t[0])
    # convert string to float(minute)
    minute = float(t[1]) / 60
    return hour + minute

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the error I get after running check.

[image] I don't know why I am getting this results from check

Comment: What are the test cases provided in the problem and which one is giving you error?

Comment: Not really enough for us to go on. The error message seems to focus on the `convert` function but that function has no obvious problem. Either there is something about the problem description that you haven't mentioned (which is something which you never actually gave) or it is a bug in the automated grading system.

Comment: I get zero error from testing my code as per problem descriptions. I only get errors when I run check.

Comment: I have added some more details about the problem set on the question.

Comment: Please no images where a link (e.g. to [Meal Time - CS50's Introduction to Programming with Python](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/1/meal/)) or - even better - text can give context. Ask a question in body and title, remove socializing. Consult [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure program and divide the problem into following **testable** functions:

1. read user-input (day-time like `18:15`) as string
2. convert time-string into hours as float (e.g. `18.25` for `18:15`)
3. return meal-time name for given time (or hours float)

```
# 1. Example: return a valid ISO-time in format HH:MM or show error and ask again
def ask_for_time():
    # your code using input, a prompt and maybe validation
    return '18:15'

# 2. Example: from local ISO-time format `18:15` to hours incl. fractions `18.25` 
def parse_to_hours(iso_time):
    # your code using strip, split, type-conversion and calculations
    # or use datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
    return 18.25

# 3. Example: 'dinner time' for '18:15' 
def mealtime_for(iso_time):
    hours = parse_to_hours(iso_time)
    # conditional returns
    if  hours >= 18 and hours <= 19:
        return 'dinner time'
    # default
    return 'outside meal-time'
```

#### Tests

This way each function can be tested. For example using [doctest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/doctest.html):

```
def meal_time_for(hours):
    """a doctest in a docstring
    >>> meal_time_for(1)
    outside meal-time
    >>> meal_time_for(18)
    dinner time
    >>> meal_time_for(12.75)
    lunch time
    """
    # implementation starts here
```

#### Assemble

If all test-cases have been passed, then the assembled script should work correctly.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    iso_time = ask_for_time()
    meal_time = meal_time_for(iso_time)
    print(f"{iso_time} is {meal_time}")
```

See also:

- [datetime — Basic date and time types — Python 3.11.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)
- [ISO 8601 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Local_time_(unqualified))

Answer (score 0):

Thats the code which is working 100%

```
 def main():
        exp = input('What time is it? ').strip()
        t = convert(exp)
        if 7 <= t <= 8:
            print('breakfast time')
        elif 12 <= t <= 13:
            print('lunch time')
        elif 18 <= t <= 19:
            print('dinner time')
        else:
            pass
    
    
    
    def convert(time):
    
            h, m = time.split(':')
            h = int(h)
            m = int(m)
    
            return h + m / 60
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: You need to better explain the code and why it's working

Comment: I was struggling with that problem over 2 weeks. I have no idea. It's something related to the moment when I variables h and m to integer. Value expected by function was 7.5 every single time. So, I think the tester script might be faulty.